# Any tips on getting people to play together in a squad on Battlefield 2 (or 2142)?

Tags: battlefield-2, battlefield-2142

I'm tired of joining servers and swapping around in squads looking for other people who want to stick together and play as a team. In my experience, just one good squad can win the whole round while everyone else is fighting over getting in planes and choppers. I'm about to give up and just start forming squads and trying to lead, but I really just want people to play together. Are there any tips for making this happen?

Comment: If teamwork is important to you I suggest trying out some mods, I found that users that actively invest their time in mods for those great games are often more teamwork-oriented. I personally found really great teamwork in [Project Reality](http://www.realitymod.com/about.html), though the slow pacing might discourage you; but there are other great mods out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only provide you with some suggestions;

1. Try to find servers that are focused specifically on team work, search for these on Google or websites dedicated to Battlefield multiplayer.
2. Contact players whom you've played with that have an interest in team work like yourself and play together frequently on the same server. This is often easier if you know the players i.e. work colleagues, friends etc.
3. Do try and lead, You can often surprise yourself with how well you can organise things with complete strangers. If you do a job that involves managing different people e.g. emergency services worker, then you will already have the skills to do this. If you are not then doing this can still be very beneficial because it will give you an outlet to practise and improve your communication and logistical skills.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a situation where video games and real life can go hand in hand. I've seen people with low self esteem actually feel better about themselves because they can lead complete strangers to victory in a virtual world. Also, real world experience helps a lot with this as well. REMEMBER leading takes practice, don't expect people to listen if you act like you know everything. They'll probably just mute you. Learn where the happy middle is.

Comment: Thank you for agreeing with my suggestion GQGK. It is nice to see that there is someone else who shares my view that gaming and the real world are very compatible.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly nobody have mentioned the most obvious course yet.

```
Join a clan
```

There are plenty of clan servers out there and a lot of them advertise openly that they are recruiting. A clan is a group of people that play together for improved teamwork and fun. They can be relaxed/causual or dedicated/hardcore or anything in between. You just have to find one that match your dedication.

It's **much** easier to join an existing clan than trying to start one from scratch!

**Edit:**

Some things I would look for in a clan (your preferences might vary though):

1. Democratic rule with no leader. This is gaming with friends, not the military.
2. 18+ age limit.
3. Clear ethics regarding behaviour and rules of conduct, but no public whining when outsiders don't play according to their morals. In other words friendly and honorable.
4. No required playtime, required meetings or other silliness.
5. Roughly the same time zone.
6. Required VoIP.

Comment: I was part of a clan once. I was even an administrator of their 2142 server. One of the most frustrating parts of being in that clan was that they wouldn't play as a squad or a team. There may be good clans out there, but everything I've experienced in my 42 years on this earth leads me to believe that every clan would have a couple of members -- fueled by anonymity -- who get off on being jerks, even to their own clanmates. Besides, with a wife, 3 kids and lots of charity work, I can't commit to the usual time requirements I've seen posted for most clans.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you have so bad experience from clans. My experience is all good and I have been in a small clan for 9 years now and interacted with several other small clans that also mostly seems nice. See edit above for some points that I interpret as good signs in a clan.

Comment: One big point can also be the game itself. The chance to find a nice clan might be higher in niche games than in major mainstream games. I'm just speculating now but I have had several really bad experiences with "guilds" in World of Warcraft :)

Comment: Nice edits. Upvoted despite my experiences. To wit: the clan I was in was structured in a very pseudo militaristic way. The owner was the only "general," and his right-hand sycophants where "lieutenants," and on down the line. Good call.

Comment: @david: It's all about finding the right one. For big strategic games, they are a requirement, but you should never stick with one where you're not comfortable. Some of the best experiences I've ever had were clan oriented. I still miss Planetside...I was in an all-air clan, and on a good day we could field 100+ units, skilled, and organized. Pants were soiled on a wholesale basis when we crested the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Go scouting online for people that you notice are good then Try to add them as a friend. Do this till you have a team that works well. Make them play together often or they might not get along and the extra time makes you realize everyones strengths; knowing there strengths will help you better orginize your team.